# Compile/Build Gluon Charm-Down itself

Tags: build, gluon

I would like to add some features to gluon charm-down I am currently missing. 
Too bad that no documentation exisits about how to do that.
All the steps I describe here are done on my development computer where I also develop a test-app using gluon mobile (incl. charm-down). Compiling/deploying this app I have no problem under iOS, Android, Desktop/Windows Surface.

My Development Environment is
Windows 10 /x64 Intel i7 32GB. Java 8u121 (some others too), installed Android SDK
For the iPhone I also have a Macbook here (which I do not use for development, only for compile/deployment/tests).

In order to be able to make my addons to charm-down I checked out the source from BitBucket via Mercurial.

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down

Then I changed the working directory to the checked out root (with build.gradle, gradle.properties etc.) and called
gradlew clean install

After a short while I am informed that ANDROID_HOME is not set. Well, it is set, but as Windows Enviroment. To enable gradle to have it, I added it to gradle.properties (ANDROID_HOME=C:/.....)
The directory I gave is the one containing the directories (add-ons, build-tools etc.)

No more complaints from gradle about the missing ANDROID_HOME, but now I get compile errors for missing Android Classes

```
C:\projects\Gluon-Charm\charm-down\plugins\plugin-lifecycle\android\src\main\java\com\gluonhq\charm\down\plugins\android\AndroidLifecycleService.java:30: error: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.Activity;
              ^
C:\projects\Gluon-Charm\charm-down\plugins\plugin-lifecycle\android\src\main\java\com\gluonhq\charm\down\plugins\android\AndroidLifecycleService.java:31: error: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.Application;
              ^
C:\projects\Gluon-Charm\charm-down\plugins\plugin-lifecycle\android\src\main\java\com\gluonhq\charm\down\plugins\android\AndroidLifecycleService.java:32: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;

.... many more
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the `core/android` module's build.gradle file, there is a dependency on the android.jar:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile files("$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-$androidPlatformVersion/android.jar")
    compile "org.javafxports:jfxdvk:$javafxportsVersion"
}
```

You have already defined your `ANDROID_HOME` path, but there is another variable: `$androidPlatformVersion`.

This one is defined in the `gradle.properties` file that you will find in the root of the Charm Down project, with these two properties set:

```
androidPlatformVersion=24
javafxportsVersion=8.60.8
```

You'll need to install Android SDK 24, so the dependency is resolved and `android.jar` is added.